# Using Twill's submit function when website's submit button is localized(Python)

Tags: python, python-requests, twill

I am trying to pull information from a website, and doing so requires me to log into it. All goes well until I reach the submit button:

```
MissingSchema: Invalid URL u'/index.php?r=site/login': No schema supplied. 
Perhaps you meant http:///index.php?r=site/login?
```

From what I can understand, this is happening because the website redirects itself to a page on the server. Is there a way to make the button redirect to the full page instead of a local file on the server? Or am I even correct on why this error is occuring?

Thanks In Advance

The Gist of My Code:

```
from twill.commands import *
go('panel.picklehosting.com/index.php?r=site/login')
showforms()
formclear('1')
fv("1", "name", "usrname")
fv("1", "password", "mypass")
submit()
```

Comment: Could you show the code you have so far? Thanks.

Comment: What version of twill are you using? I have tried with version 0.9 (very old, comes packaged with Debian, that is why), and it works for me.

Comment: @ClemensKlein-Robbenhaar Tried that, same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been experiencing the same issue for a site I'm creating but I think I've solved it.

use the twill's formaction() function to set the action for the page you want.  For example

```
    from twill.commands import *
    go('http://example.com/login')
    showforms() 
    fv("1", "nameField", "username")
    fv("1", "password", "password")
    formaction('form','http://example.com/login')
    submit("4")
    show()
    go('http://example.com/admin/')
```

or in your case

```
from twill.commands import *
go('panel.picklehosting.com/index.php?r=site/login')
showforms()
formclear('1')
fv("1", "name", "usrname")
fv("1", "password", "mypass")
formaction('form','panel.picklehosting.com/index.php?r=site/login')
submit()
go('panel.picklehosting.com/yourpage.php')
```

Comment: I had tried this, but had set the form action to another page, and that was the problem. Thanks!